# A regex for extracting " ; " or "=" symbols from source code?

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lex

For example

```
int val = 13;

Serial.begin(9600);

val = DigitalWrite(900,HIGH);
```

I really want to extract special symbols like `=` and `;`.

I've been able to extracted symbols that appear adjacent in the code, but I need all occurrences.

I tried `[^ "//"A-Za-z\t\n0-9]*` and `[\;\=\{\}\,]+`. Neither worked.

what's wrong?

---

i had made a rule for my scanner like below.(had been changed)

semicolon [;]([\n]|[^ "//"])

assignment (.)?[=]+

brace ([{]|[}])([\n]|[^ "//"])

roundbarcket ("()")" "

the problem was occurred like these situations

1. int val= 13;   // it couldn't recognize "=" because "val" and "=" is adjoined. i want to recognize them either adjoined or not
2. serial.read(); // it couldn't recognize () and ; with individually. if i add semicolon rule and roundbarcket rule, (); was recognized.

how can i solve them ?

Comment: If you want to recognize a single character, don't use repetition operators (`*` or `+`). Just `[...]` will match one character. Also, you don't need to backslash-escape characters inside a character class, except for backslash. So `[;={},]` is fine to match one of those characters (and, as I said, `[;={},]+` will match any number of such characters, so it will match the string `};` as a single token.

Comment: i tried [;={}]   but there was a warning. - can't find right matching
i have been struggle with dividing token.
for example
int val = 13;   case was success
int val= 13;  case wasn't success



how can i divide them ?

Comment: I think you need to show more of your scanner definition, and more clearly describe your requirements.

Comment: i had edited my question. please check it ! i really want to know what i missed.

Comment: @WonHeeLee Please don't deface your own question once it has been answered. Questions are supposed to be here for posterity, and to help future readers.

Answer (score 2):

You want to break "DigitalWrite(900,HIGH);" into "DigitalWrite" "(" "900" "," "HIGH" ")" ";". I think looping each substring is the fastest way.

```
        string text = "val = DigitalWrite(900,HIGH);";
        string[] symbols = new string[] { "(", ")", ",", "=", ";"};
        List<string> tokens = new List<string>();
        string word = "";
        for( int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++ )
        {
            string letter = text.Substring( i, 1 );
            if( !letter.Equals( " " ) )
            {
                if( tokens.Contains( letter ) )
                {
                    if( word.Length > 0 )
                    {
                        tokens.Add( word );
                        word = "";
                    }
                    tokens.Add( letter );
                }
                else
                {
                    word += letter;
                    if(i == text.Length - 1 )
                        tokens.Add( word );
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you so much. but is there any way to divide through just regex ?

Answer (score 0):

So searching for ";" and "=" is the ultimate goal you want to achieve?
In such case, why don't you just use something like `.find()` function?
Or, you can split strings by ";" first and search for "=" after.

If you want to grab text between "=" and ";", try use `=([^;]*);` or `=(.*?);`

Comment: second method which you suggested didn't work.. 
ultimate goal is extract special symbol.
val = DigitalWrite(900,HIGH);
here, i want to divide ); to ) and ; this is ultimate goal.
or any other special symbol !

Comment: you mean split DigitalWrite(900,HIGH); into "DigitalWrite" "(" "900" "," "HIGH" ")" ";"? Give us more details man.

Comment: yeah that's right ! or DigitalWrite(900,HIGH);  into "DigitaWrite"  ";" 
but i want to split it what you said i mean more detailed.
i tried to recognized identifier , digit , special symbol, comment from the source code !